# Trying to align the profile image to right but it's not happening

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, alignment

Below is the code for the Row containing three elements, back button, topic name and profile button.I want to keep back button and topic name aligned to left side and profile button to right side. I am trying to align the image to right side but it is not happening.

```
Row(
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                              child: Image(
                                image:
                                    AssetImage("assets/images/backbutton.png"),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
                              },
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Text(
                                chapter.topic,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "Raleway",
                                  fontSize: 24.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 35, 93),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  child: Image(
                                    image:
                                        AssetImage("assets/images/profile.png"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

[image: nav]

Comment: Wrap second child of Row() with Expanded widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your profile picture "Align" widget with a "Flexible" widget. and that's it!.

```
Flexible(
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: Image(
      image: AssetImage("assets/images/profile.png"),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Spacer()

```dart
Row(
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                              child: Image(
                                image:
                                    AssetImage("assets/images/backbutton.png"),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
                              },
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Text(
                                chapter.topic,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "Raleway",
                                  fontSize: 24.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 35, 93),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
Spacer(),
                            SizedBox(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  child: Image(
                                    image:
                                        AssetImage("assets/images/profile.png"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this widget hope it will help

```
ListView(
 children: const <Widget>[
Card(child: ListTile(title: Text('One-line ListTile'))),
Card(
  child: ListTile(
    leading: FlutterLogo(),
    title: Text('One-line with leading widget'),
  ),
),
Card(
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text('One-line with trailing widget'),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
  ),
),
Card(
  child: ListTile(
    leading: FlutterLogo(),
    title: Text('One-line with both widgets'),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
  ),
),
Card(
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text('One-line dense ListTile'),
    dense: true,
  ),
),
Card(
  child: ListTile(
    leading: FlutterLogo(size: 56.0),
    title: Text('Two-line ListTile'),
    subtitle: Text('Here is a second line'),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
  ),
),
Card(
  child: ListTile(
    leading: FlutterLogo(size: 72.0),
    title: Text('Three-line ListTile'),
    subtitle: Text(
      'A sufficiently long subtitle warrants three lines.'
    ),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
    isThreeLine: true,
  ),
),
```

],
)

Comment: **NOTE**: Revision 2 included a code block from the link cited, thus it's no longer a link only answer